# Apigility field accepting an array of embedded objects?

Tags: json, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'd like to create an Apigility REST service which accepts POSTs of, for example, a user object which has a field containing an array of address objects. I can define the field without validators and process the raw JSON in my code, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this where the nested objects can also be validated by Apigility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apigility has a module called content-validation -- it allows you to configure input filters for your services, and request data will be passed through the input filter for validation and an appropriate ApiProblem response is returned when validation fails. (see https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/content-validation)

That still leaves the onus on you to configure an input filter that will suit your needs.

I would check packagist.org for a JSON Schema validator library which can take a JSON schema and a JSON payload and verify that the payload is well formed according to the schema. Then you can easily implement a custom `InputFilter` and bind it to your services. This will give you validation that the main object and sub objects are well formed (ie: user has name, email, birth date and address field contains objects that all have address/street/zip/etc).